# How to get Webform Field data for a custom module?

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm trying to set up a view permission based on a webform field.  I've been able to get to my custom module using hook_webform_submission_access().

So I have an email field in the webform, and I want to check that based on the current user's email address.  Should be pretty simple, I just can't get the field data.  Anyone know?

Example:

```
if ($submission->data['field_email'] == $user->mail)
```

What is the correct syntax instead of $submission->data['field_email']

I'm on Drupal 7 and Webform 4.x branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) is installed, you can use [token_replace](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21token.inc/function/token_replace/7.x) to access Webform submission values by field name.

```
$email = token_replace('[submission:values:email]', array('webform-submission' => $submission));
```

Note: The [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module can be useful for exploring object properties and tokens (among other things).

Comment: Thanks Labracadabrador.  I do indeed have Token installed.  I'll check this out at work tomorrow and let you know!